# Dbus - fault control

Tags: dbus

Is there a method to inform a process connected via Dbus that the other process *died*?I mean could the faulty process inform the other one that he had an abnormal termination. I know that you can check the error type return but i want something else. For exemple consider we have a process waiting for an answer but we kill the other process with CTRL+C. Is there a way of notifing the other process..or you should just wait a few seconds for the response...etc

Answer (score 6):

At a low level: you can connect to the [NameOwnerChanged](http://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/dbus-specification.html#bus-messages-name-owner-changed) signal on the D-Bus daemon, which is emitted whenever a name is claimed or released on the bus. So if the worker process takes the well-known name `com.example.Foo`, you can add a match rule for `sender=org.freedesktop.DBus,path=/org/freedesktop/DBus,interface=org.freedesktop.DBus,member=NameOwnerChanged,type=signal,arg0=com.example.Foo`. (The `arg0` part of the [match rule](http://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/dbus-specification.html#message-bus-routing-match-rules) prevents you being notified for services other than the one you care about.)

Higher level: if you're waiting on the result of a method call, your binding (such as QDBus or GDBus) should call your callback with an error telling you that this is what happened. But you can also use a higher-level API for watching `NameOwnerChanged`. For GDBus, see the [g_bus_watch](http://library.gnome.org/devel/gio/2.26/gio-Watching-Bus-Names.html) family of functions.